# Should the [framework3.5] tag be merged/burninated in favor of [.net-3.5]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently 20 questions tagged [framework3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework3.5):

> Microsoft .NET framework version 3.5

There are 5,898 questions tagged [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5):

> The 3.5 version of the .NET Framework, which is based on the 2.0 .NET Framework with extra assemblies (including 3.0). Use for questions specifically related to .NET Framework 3.0. For questions on .NET Framework generally, use the .net tag.

All 20 of the [framework3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework3.5) questions do indeed deal with **.NET 3.5** as opposed to any other framework's version 3.5, so can we just eliminate it and merge its questions into [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5)?  (As there are < 50 questions we don't need to follow the full [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a clearly appropriate case for a merge. I've reviewed the questions that were originally tagged [framework3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework3.5), and then merged [framework3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework3.5) into [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5).