# Merge tags [.net-4.8] and [.net-framework-4.8]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

For .NET Framework 4.8 there appear to be two redundant tags each with similar #s of questions (~100):

- [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8)
- [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8)

I can't see how they would be different... I think they should be consolidated.

It appears that the naming convention for .NET version tags is to use the short form, like these:

- [.net-4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.6)
- [.net-4.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.7.2)

So based on that, [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8) should be merged / removed / synonym'ed into [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8).

Comment: I'm not an SME, but the [[tag:.net-framework]] tag is already a synonym of [[tag:.net]], so this sounds like it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Relevant: [.NET 5.0 and ASP.NET Core 5.0 tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400924/215552) The .NET moniker is transitioning to remove the traditional "Framework" part (the Windows-centric pieces). I think [.net-framework-4.8] is a good indication that it is the last version of the full Framework to exist. Starting with [.net-5.0], there is no more Framework. But I could be reading too much into it :).

Answer (score 14):

No, I agree that they should be consolidated, but I think to the more precise [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8) to avoid ambiguity. For the sake of consistency, if we were to tag questions from, say .NET Framework 3.0 as `.net-3.0`, there might be confusion between the framework version and the core version.

I propose:

- For .NET Framework versions: `.net-framework-x.x`, e.g. [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8)
- For .NET core versions: `.net-core-x.x`, e.g. [.net-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.1)
- For more recent .NET versions (steming from core): `.net-x`, e.g. [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5)

This follows Microsoft's naming conventions:

- Framework: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies
- Core (and future releases): https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

**Update**
I say this knowing that the response to similar requests (e.g. [Should the [framework3.5] tag be merged/burninated in favor of [.net-3.5]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403693/should-the-framework3-5-tag-be-merged-burninated-in-favor-of-net-3-5)) was to stick with `.net-x.x`. I think this is confusing now that we have .net core becoming the new .net. It's Microsoft's fault, so not blaming anyone, but it makes sense to use their naming convention in the name of consistency.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, these should be merged, with [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8) being the survivor. The convention is indeed to use the short form for .Net framework versions, see

- [.net-1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-1.0) - 29 questions
- [.net-1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-1.1) - 373 questions
- [.net-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-2.0) - 2,563 questions
- [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) - 5,915 questions
- [.net-4.0-beta-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0-beta-2) 17 questions
- [.net-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.0) - 8,755 questions
- [.net-4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.5) - 3,794 questions
- [.net-4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.6) - 405 questions
- [.net-4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.6.1) - 234 questions
- [.net-4.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.7)  - 95 questions
- [.net-4.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.7.1)  - 51 questions
- [.net-4.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.7.2) - 201 question
- [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8) - 100 questions
- [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5) - 1,129 questions (as of April 10 2021)

The tag [framework3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framework3.5) got merged into [.net-3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) a few months ago, see *[Should the [framework3.5] tag be merged/burninated in favor of [.net-3.5]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403693/3744182)*, so this should be handled similarly.  The alternative would be to alias all the above **`.net-[1-4]*`** tags to **`.net-framework-[1-4]*`**, which seems very disruptive.

**Update**

I did a quick scan through the [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8) questions (though somebody else may want to take an independent look).  I saw no problem tagging them with [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8), with the *possible* exception of *https://stackoverflow.com/q/65778805/3744182*, which I know nothing about.  Maybe somebody who knows something about [powerbi-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-desktop) could take a look to see whether a .net version tag is reasonable for this question.

**Update 2**

For reference here are the .NET Core tags as of 10 April 2021:

And for .Net core versions:

- [.net-core-rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-rc1) - 11 questions
- [.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core) - 32,632 questions
- [.net-core-1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-1.1) - 30 questions
- [.net-core-1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-1.1) - 30 questions
- [.net-core-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-2.0) - 343 questions
- [.net-core-2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-2.1) - 174 questions
- [.net-core-2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-2.2) - 213 questions
- [.net-core-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.0) - 628 questions
- [.net-core-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-3.1) - 846 questions
- [.net-core-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-5) - 34 questions

Comment: All that being said, one wonders what the tag [tag:.net-framework-version] is supposed to be for.  Its [help](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-framework-version/info) is... not really all that helpful: *Versions of .NET Framework. Each version of the framework has betas, final versions, service packs, and patches associated with it.  There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!*

Comment: This is not quite right...There is .NET Framework 1.0 - 4.8, .NET Core 1.0 - 3.1, and .NET 5.0 - 6.0.  .NET (5, 6) follows .NET Core (1.0 - 3.1) which is very different from .NET Framework - leaner, less Windows-centric, and allows use of the current version of C# (9.0)

Comment: Now that Microsoft seems to be calling the current versions just ".NET" I think we ought to update the tags to match.

Comment: @JayBuckman - *This is not quite right...* -- I guess I see tags purely as navigational aids, not as branding or teaching tools.  The purpose of these tags isn't to document the history and technology and progress of .Net, it's to find relevant questions and answers.  So version-specific tags that contain nothing more than version information seem better.  But if the community feels otherwise I wouldn't object to renaming **all** the `.net-[1-4]*` tags to `.net-framework-[1-4]*` -- as long as there's a mod willing to actually do the work.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the list doesn't include the .NET Core series.  Of course the ASP.NET Core and EF Core series are even worse since the .NET 5 line retained the 'Core' for now because the versions were already past 5.x

Comment: I kind of prefer .net-framework`, but given that MS uses the shorter version for its target monikers (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) and since every other .NET Framework tag already uses the shorter form, I vote for just sticking with the shorter form.

Answer (score 4):

This is done.

The tags have been merged into [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8), as that is the format of all of the rest of the .NET version tags.

A synonym from [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8) -> [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8) has also been created to ease searching.

Answer (score 3):

I agree; the official name for .NET is is ".NET Framework", at least up to version 5 when both the Framework and Core versions merged, so we should definitely synonymize or re-tag (if someone with 20k comes along and says "yea", since there's only 100 tags) the [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8) questions with [.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8). I'm ambivalent on a direction for the merger.

Comment: ... and rename all the other .net-x.y tags as well?

Comment: @StayOnTarget Your question is only about the 4.8 tags. I updated my answer to clarify I don't have a position on which direction we synonymize.