# Should the [.net-core-5] tag be merged into [.net-5] and made a synonym? or vice versa?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are currently 34 questions tagged [.net-core-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-5)

> The .net-core-5 tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

There are 1,129 questions tagged [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5):

> .NET 5 is the next version of .NET Core, and represents the future of .NET in general. It is targeting a release date of November, 2020, with the first preview released on March 16, 2020. Use this tag for questions about .NET 5 and .NET 5's formal specification.

I have looked through all 34 [.net-core-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-5) questions and they do, indeed, ask about .NET, and so these two tags do in fact refer to the same thing.  So, should the [.net-core-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-5) be merged into [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5) and made a synonym? Or vice versa?

Recent related questions:

- [Merge tags [.net-4.8] and [.net-framework-4.8]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406074/3744182) (answer: none yet, **no consensus**.)

  Specifically [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406116/3744182) has a roundup of .NET framework and version specific tags.
- [Should the [framework3.5] tag be merged/burninated in favor of [.net-3.5]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403693/3744182) (answer: **yes, done**).
- [What are the reasons for letting the tag [.net-framework] remain a synonym of [.net]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390625/3744182) (answer: **We're used to ".NET" meaning ".NET Framework"**).

Given that we now have two conflicts, [.net-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-4.8)/[.net-framework-4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-framework-4.8) and now [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5)/[.net-core-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-core-5), it feels like a cleanup is becoming more urgent.  I'd *strongly propose* that one of these tags be made a synonym of the other.  My *suggestion* would be that [.net-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net-5) be the survivor, since [the official name is .NET 5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five) according to Microsoft.

Comment: Seems like there's a consensus that [Jon Story's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406733/3744182) is the way to go. So, what's the process for making it happen?  Do we just upvote the proposed [tag:.net-core-5] synonym on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Synonym&filter=Suggested, or is there more to it?

Comment: Mods do keep an eye on retag-request questions, but if the community can handle it without mod intervention that's even better. Agreed this is sufficient consensus to take action, and there's already 1 vote on the synonym proposal on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-5/synonyms.  (You can also propose or vote on a synonym on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-4.8/synonyms if you have the tag-score for it; that seems obvious / non-controversial enough following the pattern, especially given upvotes on that Q, and can always be undone if it turns out to be the wrong move.)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There's no such thing as .NET Core 5, there are only a few questions under the tag, and they all relate to .NET 5 or just .NET

Your suggestion therefore seems like the logical approach, I think

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Turns out there is already a proposed tag synonym here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/.net-5/synonyms.  Those with a [rep of 2500 and net score of 5 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) on [tag:.net-5] can upvote the synonym.

Comment: @dbc: I upvoted because I'm a mod and I can do whatever I want even if I don't have any answers in [.net-5]. Which also means I can finalize the synonym right now if I so choose, and being the chaotic neutral I am I choose *not* to.

Comment: @BoltClock Has anyone Cc:'d the Microsoft branding dept? _Those_ guys are chaotic neutral.

Comment: I approved the .NET-5 synonym and merged (24 questions in the old tag and the voting here has been really strong in support)